# Join tables in laravel and show data in view

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Currently I'm working on project with **Laravel**(Im newbie to Laravel), where I have to take data from two tables and show them at Google Marker info window. **The structure of the tables is:**

**Table A**

companyID |
companyName |
companyAddress |
...

**Table B**

productID |
companyID |
productPrice |
...

**Controller**

```
$table = DB::table('tableA')
            ->join('tableB', 'tableB.companyID', 'tableA.companyID')
            ->get();

                // return this to view
                
                $array['table'][] = array(
                    'compID'=>$table->companyID,
                    'price'=>$table->productPrice
                     ...

    

                );

            }

            return view('maps')->with($array);
```

**Blade.php**

```
@foreach($table as $key)  
var html = '<h2>Company Name : ' + '{{$key['compName']}}' + '</h2><p>' + '{{$key['price']}}' + '</p>';
    
    var markerLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng({{$key['lat']}}, {{$key['long']}});
     

    var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: markerLatlng,
        icon: '{{$key['icon']}}',
    });

    bindInfoWindow(mark, map, infoWindow, html);

@endforeach
```

I joined two tables but when I go to view file and use foreach to take every company info and product price, it shows company info and the last price of every company (e.g. if a company has 4 products, I will take only the last product and price as well).

Comment: Why are you pushing the query result to an array when you can send the result itself to the view?

Answer (score 0):

It'll likely be losing the data when you are adding it to $array, try passing $table instead.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28149195)

Comment: yeah, will do in future, did this before i had enough reputation to comment, so needs must